# How to count a Number in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have the following number strings:

```
Textbox1.text / or Textbox1.Line= 1,2,3,19,29,78,48,39,40,51,53,54,69,70,71,73
Textbox2.text= / or Textbox2.Line=  1,9,3,31,29,78,45,39,40,51,59,54,69,70,71,73
textbox3.text= / or TextBox3.Line= 11,4,3,31,29,78,45,39,40,53,59,54,6974,75,76
    and Others ...
```

How can I make a Count that shows how many numbers from 1 to 10 are in the Textbox, how many numbers from 11-20, how many numbers from 31-40, and so on. Example: On line 1 - we will have 3 small numbers from 1 to 10 (1,2,3).

Comment: take a look at String.Split function

Comment: What you provided is not valid VBA syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this You will have to split the string into an array or list then compare the values in the array or list to the numbers you want. like this

```
 Dim arr1 As New List (Of String)
 arr1.AddRange(Split (TextBox1.Text, ","))
 Dim final As String
 Dim count As Integer = 0
 For Each item As String In arr1
    If CInt(item) >= 1 And  CInt(item) <= 10 Then
           count+=1
      'replace 10 with the maximum number you want and 1 with the minimum number. 
           final&=item & " "
      End If
 Next
 Msgbox("There are " & count & "numbers" & final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert a string containing a comma-separated list of integers into a string array like this

```
Dim s = "1,2,3,19,29,78,48,39,40,51,53,54,69,70,71,73"
Dim parts = s.Split(","c)
```

Then convert the string array into a list of integers

```
Dim numbers = New List(Of Integer)
For Each p As String In parts
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(p, i) Then
        numbers.Add(i)
    End If
Next
```

Now comes the counting part. With LINQ you can write

```
Dim tens = From n In numbers
            Group n By Key = (n - 1) \ 10 Into Group
            Order By Key
            Select Text = $"{ 10 * Key + 1} - {10 * Key + 10}", Count = Group.Count()
```

This

```
For Each x In tens
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Text} --> {x.Count}")
Next
```

Prints

```
1 - 10 --> 3
11 - 20 --> 1
21 - 30 --> 1
31 - 40 --> 2
41 - 50 --> 1
51 - 60 --> 3
61 - 70 --> 2
71 - 80 --> 3
```